# Can't access IIS website on port 81 from remote PC, but can on IIS server

Tags: iis

I created a IIS site with a custom website on port 81 on a server thats not my own machine.

From the server itself, I can access the custom website.

But then from my local machine I want to visit the website but I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

But from my local machine, I can access the default website on port 80.

Does anyone know what I can check?

Comment: Check if the port is open on your network equipment. Can't provide a proper answer without more details on network layout.

Comment: I believe @gronostaj is saying you need to check your software or hardware firewall to make sure port 81 is open. If this is Windows Server I imagine installing IIS role automatically allows port 80 in Windows Firewall, but since you're using a custom port it might need to be whitelisted. It'd also be good to change your title as you say website works on server hosting it, but not remote PC which your title says otherwise

Comment: On the server can you run: `netstat -ano | find ":81"` and paste the output in the question?